# Regular expression to filter URLs?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to filter some specific URLs using Regex in Google analytics.
It should only filter the below format URLs from the all URLs recorded:

```
/job/41-content-verification?action=register
/job/62-data-verification?action=register
/job/33-data-entry?action=register
```

Like ***starts with '/job/' then 'some string/data' and ends with '?action=register'***

I need the regex to be put in Google analytics filter. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/job/.+?\?action=register$
```

Comment: You want to end with $ otherwise it will also match /job/33-data-entry?action=registerxyz

Answer (score 2):

```
^\/job\/.+?action=register$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/24

Comment: You probably want .+ not .* as he said "then 'some string/data'"

Answer (score 0):

```
^\/job\/[a-z0-9-]+\?action=register$
```